# WPF & RenderTierCapability, what could cause a machine to be dropped from Tier 2 to 0?

Tags: directx, wpf

I'm having an issue on some imaged machines where they will started out on Tier 2 and after some time of use (they are well spec'd kiosk machines, quad-core, Nvidia 550Ti), they drop to Tier 0 and effectively become useless. Restarting the machine doesn't seem to help. This is a problem more than just "missing hardware acceleration" because my application requires D3DImage to function (which requires Tier 2).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out.  Using LogMeIn Ignition which is supposed to work with Aero.  Using the Display Accelerator turned off aero and killed hardware acceleration due to it using their own video driver while I was logged in to diagnose this.  Turning it off worked but now it's so slow over the wire it's impossible to use.  TeamViewer is a better option.